# Uncheck use Androidx artifacts

Tags: android-studio, androidx

I have made some projects using androidx, today i decided to start new progject without use of androidx and my starter template shows this

[image: cant uncheck use of androidx]
<sub>(source: [mobytop.ru](https://mobytop.ru/example1.png))</sub>

I cant't uncheck 'Use androidx.* artifacts' checkbox. How can i solve this strange behavior and make this checkbox active back?

Comment: The only way I've been able to make the option uncheckable is by uninstalling the Android 10 SDK completely. Is it possible that with Android 10, androidx artifacts are a must?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved my issue by deleting latest Android Q sdk.
To do this go to `Tools->Sdk Manager->Appearence & Behavior->System Settings->Android Sdk` and remove tick from Android 9.+ (Q).

Answer (score 1):

I followed this step: Tools>Sdk Manager-> Appearance &Behavior ->System Settings -> Android SDK.  then check the Show package details in the bottom right. Next, I check mark everything under android 7.1.1, next uncheck everything android 8 and above. the click apply. that way when you start a now project, you will have the option to uncheck androidx artifacts in the bottom after you select the activity.

Comment: No need uncheck android 8, only android 9 and all components inside

Answer (score 0):

Go to the SDK manager in android studio and uncheck android Q ( 29 ).